# Trying to get an image showed in golang template

Tags: html, go, templates

Im using golang to set up a server and im executing templates inside of it. Inside of my templates I'm trying to get an image, but for some reason nothing i try works. In the console it says gives that error:
﻿

```
GET http://localhost:5051/static/photo_2021-06-17_14-18-09.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Go code :

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    // "io/ioutil"
)


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/a", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":5051", nil)

    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/main.html")
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "main", struct{}{})
}
```

Template code:

```
{{ define "main" }}
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="../static/photo_2021-06-17_14-18-09.jpg">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
{{ end }}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The error is `404 (Not found)`. That means that the particular resource (jpeg filename) that you requested was not located by the server.

Comment: Yes, but i dont understand the problem. When I just open the html file in the browser everything perfectly.

Comment: Are you running your binary from the directory where `static` is?

Comment: Yes, i do. my go file is located in the same directory

Comment: It doesn't matter where the go file is, it matters where you run it from.

Comment: Yes, i run it from the same directory

Comment: where should i use it?

Comment: The static handler is not registered before the server is run. Move the call `http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))` to the line before `http.ListenAndServe(":5051", nil)`.   This was not the problem here, but you can make your template position independent by using an absolute URL path for files in the static directory.

Comment: IT WORKED!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the http.ListenAndServe line below the static handler.